# Android geolocation platform - KitLocate

Tags: android, geolocation, geofencing, google-geolocation

I am trying to develop an application usign geolocation and geofencing. The Google geofencing apis are there, but I found another platform KitLocate that provides an sdk for these purposes with a simple documentation. Is there anyone that tried this services? Also, are there other platforms that can be used for geolocation or the best technique is to work with the google apis?

Comment: Probably, yes, best for what.

Comment: Creation and management of geofences as well as battery efficiency when GPS,WiFi or network location is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"best" is always hard to define. I've worked with KitLocate on iOS - It's a good platform, easy to use and free for non-enterprise customers. They don't impact the battery life too much, which is nice. Customer support is also very good. The company was bought recently by Yandex, so I guess they're here to stay.

I think the most important advantage they have over Google APIs is the fact that they are cross platform, so you can manage all your Android/iOS users at one place.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can't upvote you yet though! By best I mean how easy is to use the platform in comparison with the Google APIs and the reliability of the service because you don't write it. I tried to play a little with their sdk, but I saw that the web dashboard and analytics pages are under developement so I am not sure about the information they give you back from their site.